# Can't make Quill editor name size options when I use inline styles

Tags: angularjs, quill

I need to use inline styles so I used this code:

```
var BackgroundStyle = Quill.import('attributors/style/background');
var ColorStyle = Quill.import('attributors/style/color');
var SizeStyle = Quill.import('attributors/style/size');
Quill.register(BackgroundStyle, true);
Quill.register(ColorStyle, true);
Quill.register(SizeStyle, true);
```

If I just add this code nothing works. So, I changed the toolbal config:

```
    var config = {
        modules: {
        toolbar: [
...

            [{ 'size': ['10px', false, '18px', '32px'] }],  // custom dropdown
]}};

editor = new Quill(editorElem, config);
```

It starts working but in the dropdown for the size all the values look like "Normal":
[image]

So how to change the dropdown too?

Comment: Nice to hear that you find a solution, post it as a anwser to help future users :)

Comment: You deserve a star brother

Answer (score 0):

Change the styles too. Add this code to make everything work (do the same for other styles):

```css
.ql-snow .ql-picker.ql-size .ql-picker-label[data-value="32px"]::before{
    content: 'Huge';
}
.ql-snow .ql-picker.ql-size .ql-picker-item[data-value="32px"]::before {
  content: 'Huge';
  font-size: 32px;
}
```

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/49738310/2) to the question [Can't make Quill editor name size options when I use inline styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49738310/cant-make-quill-editor-name-size-options-when-i-use-inline-styles) by the OP [mimic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/46503/mimic) under CC BY-SA 3.0.</sub>